# Using AWS to capture and store emails sent out from a server

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Currently our server connects to the Amazon SES SMTP interface to send out email reminders to clients, emails that are undelivered and bounce back are forwarded onwards using the SNS service.
All this works perfectly.

There has never been the capability to store the email reminders that get sent out as the server simply fires and forgets.

I would like to add this capability using the AWS architecture to capture and store the emails.

I think this possible using some combination of SES and SQS and S3 but has anyone got any suggestions on how to architect this requirement within AWS to achieve the goal? I am unsure of the best approach and I'm concerned that I might be missing some component of AWS that could easily achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution hidden in the identity management section of AWS, it is here that you set up the process of forwarding email notifications. 
[Location of notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rutuk.png)

**Step 1** Click on the domain to edit the notifications and create a new SNS (Push Notification Service‎) topic for each type of notification (Bounce, Complaint or Delivery)

**Step 2** Create a new Queue (SQS)

**Step 3** [Go to SNS and create a new subscription to link the queue and the notification together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G02Yu.png)

**Step 4** Use Lamdba to process your queue and direct the output to wherever you wish

**Note**  If you are sending large quantities of email then this solution may cost considerably more and you should research different solutions including using Cloudwatch and Kinesis